# 'If you asked me now' or 'If you ask me now'?

Tags: grammar, tenses, conditionals

What is the difference between those two:

- *'If you asked me now...'*
- *'If you ask me now...'*

Comment: Why do you think that one of them may be incorrect?

Answer (score 3):

You have heard both used because both are grammatical. Check out [this page](http://www.ef.com/english-resources/english-grammar/conditional/) for an explanation of the different ways to phrase a conditional statement in English.

Consulting this page, in particular, the first example you list, "if you asked me now," is Type 2 Conditional, and the second, "if you ask me now" is either Type 0 or Type 1, depending on the rest of the sentence.